# Square factorization in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Note - Go down to the edits if you want the more recent code, look here if you want to see the original question. I have made edits to the code, however, so mistakes in this code block may be outdated.

---

As a self-taught Python 3 programmer, I have been working on a way to simplify radical expressions. The one part of the program that does not work, however, is the square factorization. I have a function that detects square numbers, which works fine. The function that does not work is the following-

```
    def sqfactorslist(num):
        factors = []
        counter = num // 2 + 1

        while counter > 0:

            if counter == 1:
                factors.append(num) #if no square ints other than 1 square into num, append and finish.

            while is_square(counter) == True and counter != 1: #If counter is a valid square integer, append it's square and subtract it from num. 

                if (counter ** 2) >= num:
                    factors.append(counter ** 2)
                    num -= counter ** 2

                else: #Else, continue with a program. 
                    break

            if counter > 0:
                counter -= 1 #If counter more than 0, subtract 1 from it

            else:
                break #If number is equal to or less than 0, break

        return factors #If the input is 32, this should return 16 and 2.
```

It doesn't return anything other than an infinite loop. Anyone know whats wrong?

---

Edit 1 -- I have changed the program so that it runs, but now I have a stranger issue: If I input a square number as num, for example 16, I get a number larger than the input, e.x. 81, in the return list. I get no returned elements for a non-square number. 
To make it run, I indented the first if statement after the end of the second while loop.

---

Edit 2 -- I have changed the program again, but I come up with another issue similar to the one above. After eliminating another mistake, where I squared numbers already shown to be square, found in the second while loop,  the program now has a new problem - If I use a non-square integer, it returns an empty list, and if I use a square integer, like 16, it gives me an infinite loop. Current code shown below --

```
def findsqfactors(num):
    factors = []
    counter = num // 2 + 1

    while counter > 0:

        if counter == 1:
            factors.append(num) #If no square ints other than 1 square into num, append then finish. 

        while is_square(counter) == True and counter != 1: #

            if counter >= num:
                factors.append(counter) 
                num -= counter


            else:
                break


            if counter > 0:
                counter -= 1
        else:
            break

    return factors
```

Comment: What are you inputting for `num` when you get an infinite loop?

Comment: while is_square(counter) is your infinite loop. It will never exit

Comment: `It doesn't return anything other than an infinite loop. Anyone know whats wrong?` Sounds like the perfect time to throw `pdb` in

Comment: @Kh40tiK , PDB? I looked at python.org, and used it as suggested, but got this, paraphrased, using step - <string>(1)<module>() -> step -> --Return-- -> <string>(1)<module>() -> step -> (pathway to pdb) self.quitting = True -> done

Comment: I suggest you read [ask] and [mcve]. When you (radically) change your question, you may consider starting a new question on SO, as it's rather confusing decerning what the actual problem is with the current changing target,